# Multiply Value of Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiplication

I'm trying to get the multiplication of two values ​​from an array but have not achieved using the code below:

```
var total_ust = new Array();
var total_zqnt_service = new Array();
var array = 1;
<PDM_LIST SOURCE=args.children>
total_zust[array] = $args.children.category.zust; 
total_zqnt_service[array] = $args.children.zqnt_service
array++;
</PDM_LIST>
var total_qtd_ust = 0;
var total_qtdServ = 0;
function zloadTotalUst(){
    for (var i=1; i <= $args.children.length; i++){ 
        total_qtd_ust = total_qtd_ust + total_zust[i];
}
for (var i=1; i <= $args.children.length; i++){ 
    total_qtdServ = total_qtdServ + total_zqnt_service[i];
}
valor_final = total_qtd_ust * total_zqnt_service;

if("$prop.form_name_3" == "edit"){
if("$args.id" == 0 && ("$args.ztotal_ust" == null || "$args.ztotal_ust" == 0)){
document.main_form.elements["SET.ztotal_ust"].value = "$args.children.category.zust;";
}
if("$args.id" != 0 && ("$args.ztotal_ust" != null && "$args.children.length" != 0)){
document.main_form.elements["SET.ztotal_ust"].value = valor_final;
}
}
}
```

In the code i have two arrays and a function to make the sum and the multiplication of this values, exemple:

The value of the sum of the array1 (**total_zust**) is "12" and the array2 (**total_zust**) is "4", i need to multiply this and put the value of this multiplication on the field "X" like the line:

```
document.main_form.elements["SET.ztotal_ust"].value = valor_final;
```

Would know tell me what am I doing wrong?
Many thanx for the help!!!

Comment: Have you opened your console (hit F12)? That code isn't valid with all of that `<PDM` stuff in there.

Comment: That's some very complicated code to "get the multiplication of two values ​​from an array". Read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Statements such as `if("$prop.form_name_3" == "edit")` don't seem to have much of a chance of doing what you want.

Comment: @MikeC, this code is to customize some works in CA Service Desk Manager application, the `<PDM` is a internal expression.
I use a code like this to make the sum of other values and it works.
Im in trouble to make the multiplication of this values.

Comment: @DiegoLima the first line, `var total_ust = new Array();` looks like it should be `var total_zust = new Array();` Is this a typo in the posted code?

Comment: @Traktor53 i forgot to put the correct variable, sorry!! Even so, im still in trouble with this code!! =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code for the example below and everything is working perfectly!!!

Many thanx to all!!

```
var total_zust = new Array();
var total_zqnt_service = new Array();
var array = 1;
<PDM_LIST SOURCE=args.children>
total_zust[array] = $args.children.category.zust;
total_zqnt_service[array] = $args.children.zqnt_service;
array++;
</PDM_LIST>
var total_qtd_ust = 0;
var total_qtdServ = 0;
function zloadTotalUst(){
for (var i=1; i <= $args.children.length; i++){ 
total_qtd_ust = total_qtd_ust + (total_zust[i] * total_zqnt_service[i]);
total_qtdServ = total_qtdServ + total_zqnt_service[i];
}
if("$prop.form_name_3" == "edit"){
if("$args.id" == 0 && ("$args.ztotal_ust" == null || "$args.ztotal_ust" == 0)){
document.main_form.elements["SET.ztotal_ust"].value = "$args.children.category.zust";
}
if("$args.id" != 0 && ("$args.ztotal_ust" != null && "$args.children.length" != 0)){
document.main_form.elements["SET.ztotal_ust"].value = total_qtd_ust;
}
}
```